# JavaScript If Less Than Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, custom-data-attribute

in my html I have the following:

```
<div class="boxS" data-catTotal="19"></div>
<div class="boxS" data-catTotal="12"></div>
<div class="boxS" data-catTotal="4"></div>
<div class="boxS" data-catTotal="8"></div>
<div class="boxS" data-catTotal="4"></div>
<div class="boxS" data-catTotal="1"></div>
```

And my JavaScript as follows:

```
var sizeBoxMax = null;
var sizeNew;
$(".boxS").each(function(){

    var sizeBox = $(this).attr("data-catTotal");
    alert($(this).attr("data-namez") + " " + sizeBox + " " + sizeBoxMax);

    if (sizeBox < sizeBoxMax) {
        sizeNew = (sizeBox / sizeBoxMax) * 100;
        sizeNew = Math.ceil(sizeNew.toFixed(0));
        $(this).attr("style", "width: " + sizeNew + "% !important");
    }

    else {
        if (sizeBoxMax == null) {
            sizeBoxMax = $(this).attr("data-catTotal");
        }
        // alert($(this).attr("data-namez") +" "+ sizeBox);
    }

});
```

The problem is that the `if` statement isn't being accessed, even when the `sizeBoxMax` is 19 the whole time. What happens is that `19`, `12`, and `1` are working right, but the rest are unaffected. Any ideas on what I could do? I tried to `parseInt()` but I just get `NaN`. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Why not ask us about what you're really trying to do; setting the width of all the elements to something etc. There are probably easier ways to do it.

Comment: If you use `Number()` instead of `parseInt()`, does it make a difference?

Comment: try checking for null on sizeBoxMax before comparing... http://jsfiddle.net/5WzVz/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to set `sizeBoxMax` inital value to an `integer` instead of `null`

You can see the result working in [jsuna's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5WzVz/) when using a int value.

Comment: or yes, init to a numeric value!

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much, that worked! Is it just the initialization that needs to happen? Because I need to go through all the class `boxS` and find which `data-` has the largest value, and that's the value of the `sizeBoxMax`. It needs to be dynamic, could I set it to `0` and it work properly, as in enter the else statement first?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Christopher Marshall's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23504607/209259) you should be using [jQuery's Data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

```
var sizeBox = $(this).data("catTotal");
```

and

```
sizeBoxMax = $(this).data("catTotal");
```

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null). A value is only converted to a number if doing so doesn't change the value's representation. For example, "1E02" and "100.000" are equivalent as numbers (numeric value 100) but converting them would alter their representation so they are left as strings. The string value "100" is converted to the number 100.

Comment: I've ran into reference issues with .data(). The .data() get's cached and on second call doesn't update the variable properly, but I'm probably using it wrong (or something)

Comment: Same thing here, I tried using `.data()` and it wasn't working, so I had to sadly resort to `.attr()`.

Comment: Make sure you DON'T use the prefix with data, e.g. `data-whatever=""` = `.data("whatever")`.